# Mean of a bias coin with probability of heads 'p'

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, means

Consider the experiment of tossing a bias coin with probability *p* of Heads *n* times. Let X be the number of Heads obtained, which has the binomial(n,p) distribution. Calculate the mean $\mu _X=E\left(X\right)$.

Hint: X can be expressed in terms of the indicator functions as

$X=I_{H_1}+I_{H_2}+...+I_{H_n}$

where each $H_k$ is the event 'Heads on the k-th toss'.

I am looking for how to do this as well as the answer. If possible, I would like to see step by step so I can get a clear understanding of the whole problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$E(X) = E(I_{H_1}+\dots+I_{H_n}) = E(I_{H_1})+\dots+E(I_{H_n})$$
So all that remains is to find $E(I_{H_i})$ for each $i=1,\dots,n$. The expected value of an indicator function is just the probability of the event it indicates.

In more detail, $I_{H_i}$ only takes the values 0 and 1, so
$$
E(I_{H_i}) = 0\cdot P(1_{H_i}=0) + 1\cdot P(1_{H_i}=1) = P(H_i).
$$

Comment: Okay, so the fact that the question mentions that the number of heads obtained (X) has a binomial (n,p) distribution is not necessary to solve the question?

Comment: Well, the fact that $X\sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$ is what allows you to conclude that $X=1_{H_1}+\dots+1_{H_n}$ where $H_1,\dots,H_n$ are independent events with probability $p$. Some take this as the definition of the binomial distribution. But if you allowed to take the hint as a "given," then all you need is the hint.

Comment: So the final answer is: np?

Comment: @user485656 yes!